# Forwarding specific traffic to another LAN

Tags: networking, server, lan, routing, ip-forward

There's a LAN of about 40 computers all running Ubuntu 15.04. 
There are two servers, both Ubuntu 15.04.

One of the servers will act as a SVN repo server and other as a firewall-and-transparent-proxy server.

The repo server needs to be on a different LAN than the rest of the computers. Is it possible to direct only the SVN traffic to that server and block the internet on it?

Edit:

internet-->proxy server . this proxy server will further support two networks (possible?) the svn server (say192.168.0.x/30) and the LAN (say 10.0.0.0/24).. now what I need is to be able to forward only svn data (through apache server) be forwarded to svn server. Since apache uses port 80, ipforwarding will send all :80 data to svn server.. I don't want that.

Re-edit:

> ```
>    +-----------+      Internet  +-----------+
>    |  LAN      |          |     | SVN (3690)|
>    |           |        <-+     |           |
>    |           |--|Something?|--|           |
>    |           |                |           |
>    |           |                |           |
>    +-----------+                +-----------+
> ```

Comment: Hmm, directing the traffic is what your router does anyway, if the svn server is addressed. If it is addressed with non-svn stuff, likely no process will listen. In the worst case you need to configure its firewall to take care. Directing this traffic somewhere else would be of no use. But maybe I don't fully understand your intent.

Comment: @Harald i'm not sure fow to attach a photo to the comments else i would have.. and  the comment section is not letting me be fancy with drawing using symbols... internet-->proxy server . this proxy server will further support two networks (possible?) the svn server (say192.168.0.x/30) and the LAN (say 10.0.0.0/24).. now what i need is to be able to forward only svn data (through apache server) be forwarded to  svn server.
since apache uses port 80, ipforwarding will send all :80 data to svn server.. i don't want that. am i making any sense?

Comment: If you want to provide more information to your question, it is anyway best to edit the question, not put this into comments.

Comment: @Harald okay.. but do you have an answer for this?

Comment: Still unclear what you want. IP routing or web proxying? For the latter, I think your keywords for apache setup are "virtual host" and "*reverse* proxy".

Comment: @Harald IP forwarding.. I would love to be able to forward only SVN data to the SVN server

Comment: Ok, then you should take the keyword proxy out of your question. This sounds mor like NAT https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation . Set up your router to forward some port to the svn server. You might want a create a dyndns entry https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_DNS in addition.

Comment: @Harald i have figured out most of the things except one: how can i forward data from LAN on port 3690 through eth0 to eth1 on my proxy server so that the svn server on the other end can recieve it.

Comment: If you are not talking about HTTP, please do not talk about proxy. I still don't get how your network setup is. I can only guess it is : internet->router->server X(you call it proxy)->svn. Why does the traffic have to go through server X? Is your svn-machine not connected to the router. Well its all guessing if you do not clearly show your network structure. Which machine is connected to which and which network addresses do they have. Do not miss to put the router into the picture.

Comment: @Harald Sorry for the late reply, I hope you reply back too. This is my plan. I need the LAN to be able to access Internet through a server (for DHCP, NATing, Transparent proxy). The LAN and SVN server should be on different networks.. how do i forward traffic from LAN of port 3690 to SVN server through this server? I can do the rest

Comment: So |something?| is a linux server with eth0 and eth1 and one of the network cards is on network 192.168.0.0 and the other is on network 10.0.0.0.  You want that another machine, say 192.168.0.123 shall access the svn on a server with, say, 10.0.0.177.  This looks like you need a route on the 192.168.0.123 which say that anything 10.x.x.x shall go to |something?|. Then you need to configure |something?| as a router, which I have never done. At least, it seems to involve enabling ip-forwarding and a decent route entry too. This works then for all ports not for the specific one.

Comment: @Harald yes it needs ip forwarding and i don't know how to configure it either.